# jenkins pipeline additional parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a step in a shared library to set build properties with some common parameters. I'm trying to pass additional parameters to the step such that:

```
def call(buildParams = []) {
  def commonParams = [
        booleanParam(name: 'release', defaultValue: false, description: 'Release the project'),
  ]
  properties([
        parameters(commonParams + buildParams)
  ])
}
```

I'm calling this like:

```
standardProperties(buildParams = [booleanParam(name: 'test', defaultValue: false, description: 'test'))
```

However I get an NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.JobPropertyStep$Execution.run(JobPropertyStep.java:127)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.JobPropertyStep$Execution.run(JobPropertyStep.java:92)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousStepExecution.start(AbstractSynchronousStepExecution.java:42)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:229)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:153)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the invocation of your standardProperties method doesn't need to specify `buildParams =`, this is part of the interface. Try:

```
standardProperties([booleanParam(name: 'test', defaultValue: false, description: 'test')])
```

For easy reading I recommend

```
List params = [
    booleanParam(name: 'test', defaultValue: false, description: 'test')
]
standardProperties(params)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had other arguments to the step, that's why I named it and stripped others for posting.

Comment: Then use standardProperties(buildParams : [ ...) : a colon instead of the equals sign for the named parameter syntax

Comment: You also had a comma at the end of the array, which might(?) result in a null element ?

Comment: Groovy doesn't mind final trailing comma in arrays (or at least Jenkins CPE doesn't)

Comment: Thanks all for input. The NPE was because the way I was using the elvis operator. A colleague of mine pointed out I need to parens to do what I wanted -- params or [], not [] for the whole thing.